# How to use travis-ci or grunt to test with different versions of a script

Tags: javascript, travis-ci, gruntjs

I'm using Travis-CI to lint and test frontend javascript code programmatically (using Gruntjs).

My question is if I build a plugin and I want to test it on multiple version of a script, how can I manage this ?

For example, a simple use case would be if I build a jQuery plugin, can I ask grunt or travis to run it through test using version 1.6, then 1.7 and then 1.8 ?

Answer (score 4):

I used the instructions from http://manuelvanrijn.nl/blog/2012/06/22/integrate-travis-ci-into-grunt/ to get the Travis-CI integration working.

For the multiple jQuery versions, check out how jQuery valitation does it https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/test/index.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for a more robust solution where you could go farther than jQuery. Based on `npm` or some ressource loader like `bower` or `volo` to get scipts version and automate the testing with versions you define... Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

On travis.ci, the best solution is to use their build matrix.

For example, using an environment variable to store the version to use, you can specify a particular version after `npm install`:

```
env:
  - JQUERY=1.11
  - JQUERY=2.2
  - JQUERY=3.0.0-beta1
install:
  - npm install
  - npm install jquery@$JQUERY
```